# USB Ports not working with Ubuntu Linux 14

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb

I installed and configured Ubuntu Linux 14 for dual boot setup on my Windows 8.1 machine. Everything is working fine except for 2.0 USB ports. They simply don't do anything when I plug either a plain old USB stick, or even my USB mouse. I read about lsusb, and below is the output.

```
jason@JasonsUbuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05ca:18c4 Ricoh Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0489:e036 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:002d Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I can tell that the 2.0 USB ports are 'registered' (not sure what linux terminology is for that) but they just seem to be dead ports. Where can I go from here to further troubleshoot the issue?

**Edit:**

Here's the output from lsusb -t, I hope this new information is useful.

```
jason@JasonsUbuntu:~$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
```

Comment: They are working on Windows? Have you tested this booting from (Linux) CD, or better from Linux bootable USB? Is this on cold-boot or after running windows a warm reboot?

Comment: `lsusb -t` is useful for this as it shows the hubs and what's connected to them in a tree view.

Comment: @Anthon Both USB 2.0 ports work perfectly fine on Windows 8.1. I'm not sure what you mean by cold/warm reboot so I will explain how my system is setup for dual boot. When I restart my machine I am prompted with 4 options. 1. Ubuntu 2. advanced options for ubuntu 3. Windows boot manager 4. system setup. option 1 starts my ubuntu OS and option 3 starts my Windows OS. I guess this is the normal way for dual boot to work but since I have never done this before I'm not %100 sure that it is.

Comment: @garethTheRed I added the output from lsusb -t but it doesn't mean much to me.

Comment: @Jason warm boot would be if you first start in Windows, then restart and select Ubuntu, without completely shutting down. Sometimes Windows loads program code in device which block Linux from initialising those devices, although I have not seen that with USB. Can you boot Linux from CD/USB and check if things work?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?  This issue was raised as a bug late last year - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1210858

Comment: @garethTheRed 3.13.0-35-generic

Comment: @Anthon I did both a Cold reboot + booted directly from USB and USB 2.0 is still not working

Comment: @Jason does that mean you can boot from USB and then it stops working or do you use USB 3.0 to boot from?

Comment: @Anthon I can only boot from USb 3.0.